# Adding ArrayList to recyclerView

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to add an ArrayList to my RecyclerView. The problem is that it's not setting up anything, only blank spaces are present.

The code for my mainActivity is

```
ArrayList<String> Size = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(SizeArrayFinal));

rec = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.SizeRecycler);
rec.setHasFixedSize(true);
rec.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
sizeConstructorList = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i <= Size.size(); i++){
   SizeConstructor sizeConstructor = new SizeConstructor(Size);
   sizeConstructorList.add(sizeConstructor);
}

recAdapter = new SizeAdapter(sizeConstructorList,getApplicationContext());
rec.setAdapter(recAdapter);
```

The code for my Adapter class is

```
public class SizeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SizeAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<SizeConstructor> sizeConstructorList;
    private Context context;

    public SizeAdapter(List<SizeConstructor> sizeConstructorList, Context context) {
        this.sizeConstructorList = sizeConstructorList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public SizeAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.size_view, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SizeAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        SizeConstructor sizeConstructor = sizeConstructorList.get(position);
        holder.button1.setText(sizeConstructor.getSize());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return sizeConstructorList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView button1;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            button1 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.SizeButton);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally my constructor class is

```
public class SizeConstructor {

    String Size;

    public SizeConstructor(ArrayList<String> sizeArray) {
    }

    public SizeConstructor(String size) {
        Size = size;
    }

    public String getSize() {
        return Size;
    }
}
```

The issue is that the code is not setting the values in the recyclerView.

Please refer to the image below to see the issue.
[image: This is the reference Image]

Moreover there is a huge Gap below which is not required as i was setting the orientation to be horizontal.
Any help would be great as I have to submit this project really soon.

```
RecycleView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
```

`rec.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);`

After i added this line....it is again showing just the first textView instead of complete arrayList.

I wanted to make the layout horizontal.
I tried to add tge code for horizontal layout im XML file but it wasn't making it horizontal....

Comment: Can you share the xml file please. May be RecyclerView height problem.

Comment: The height is set to wrap_content

Comment: Ok please debug and see what getitemcount() returns. And follow parag pawar's answer.

Comment: share the xml please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing the entire ArrayList Instead of the actual size.
So change this line:

```
SizeConstructor sizeConstructor = new SizeConstructor(Size);
```

to

```
SizeConstructor sizeConstructor = new SizeConstructor(Size.get(indexValue));
```

So finally to this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= Size.size(); i++){

     SizeConstructor sizeConstructor = new SizeConstructor(Size.get(i));
     sizeConstructorList.add(sizeConstructor);
 }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Are you sure i can add getSize() method there.....coz it is not letting me write this line.

Comment: The constructor accept an arraylist so size will not be accepted.

Comment: @jpsingh you have 2 constructors, one of them accepts the string value, you should not be adding an entire ArrayList into your POJO class, not for at least this case

Comment: And what do you mean it is not letting you write this?

Comment: Remove this constructor: `public SizeConstructor(ArrayList<String> sizeArray) {
}` I don't think you need it

Comment: As you are not doing anything with the arraylist, why you are passing an arraylist in the constructor? If you want to show same size(say 5) to your recyclerview item you should try above answer.

Comment: It is throwing up an error.....ie.....indexOutOfBoundException: Index: 6, Size: 6

Comment: make the for loop condition as `i  <  Size.size()` instead of `i <= Size.size()`

Answer (score 1):

change this code

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= Size.size(); i++){

            SizeConstructor sizeConstructor = new SizeConstructor(Size);
            sizeConstructorList.add(sizeConstructor);
        }
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i <= Size.size(); i++){

            SizeConstructor sizeConstructor = new SizeConstructor(Size.get(i));
            sizeConstructorList.add(sizeConstructor);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

in `SizeConstructor` change constructor to this:

```
public SizeConstructor(ArrayList<String> sizeArray) {

  Size = String.valueOf(sizeArray != null ? sizeArray.size() : 0);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and now it is setting the text as null on single textView instead of 6 7 8 9 on 4 different textViews

Comment: Yeah it is working....however there are 4 elements in arrayList, 6, 7, 8, 9....and instead of making for different textViews with 6, 7, 8 and 9....it is just showing single textView with 6 in it